# How can I make a popup window without blocking main program in PyQt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I am working on a pyqt5 based GUI python program. When I press compute program starts calculating and I would like to let user knows that it is calculating. I tried to make QDialog with .gif animation when calculating starts and close it when it ends. I ran into a problem, I either get blank window without .gif animation or animation starts but it is blocking main window. I also tried with QThread but no luck. I found out that QDialog completely blocks your application execution. Could you please help me how to solve this? Thank you for your responses!

Here is code of animation dialog class, where main program executes but .gif animation doesn't show up:

```
class LoadingScreen:
    """Loading screen animation."""
    def __init__(self, gif_path):
        self.dlg = QDialog()
        self.dlg.setWindowTitle("Loading")
        self.dlg.setWindowModality(False)
        self.dlg.setFixedSize(200, 200)
        self.dlg.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.CustomizeWindowHint)
        self.label_animation = QLabel(self.dlg)
        self.movie = QMovie(gif_path)
        self.label_animation.setMovie(self.movie)

    def start_animation(self):
        self.movie.start()
        self.dlg.show()

    def stop_animation(self):
        self.movie.stop()
        self.dlg.done(0)
```

Comment: QDialog does *not* block anything, if you call and execute it correctly. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including the part where youre creating and showing the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you haven't posted any minimal example, so I created one, and this works fine, with no blocking of the main function, loads the gif and plays on the button press.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QLabel, QMainWindow, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize

class LoadingScreen:
    """Loading screen animation."""
    def __init__(self, gif_path):
        self.dlg = QDialog()
        self.dlg.setWindowTitle("Loading")
        self.dlg.setWindowModality(False)
        self.dlg.setFixedSize(350, 350)
        self.dlg.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.CustomizeWindowHint)
        self.label_animation = QLabel(self.dlg)
        self.movie = QMovie(gif_path)
        self.movie.setScaledSize(QSize(self.dlg.width(), self.dlg.height()))
        self.label_animation.setMovie(self.movie)

    def start_animation(self):
        self.movie.start()
        self.dlg.show()

    def stop_animation(self):
        self.movie.stop()
        self.dlg.done(0)

class AppWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AppWindow, self).__init__()
        self.pushButton_load = QPushButton("Press to \nLoad animation",self)
        self.pushButton_load.setFixedSize(150,50)
        self.pushButton_load.move(50, 50)
        self.setFixedSize(300,150)
        self.pushButton_load.clicked.connect(self.load_animation)
        self.animation_started = False

    def load_animation(self):
        if not self.animation_started:
            self.animation_started = True
            self.pushButton_load.setText("Press to \nStop animation")
            gif_path = "funny.gif"  # path to the gif file you want to load
            self.loading_screen = LoadingScreen(gif_path)
            self.loading_screen.start_animation()
        else:
            self.animation_started = False
            self.pushButton_load.setText("Press to \nLoad animation")
            self.loading_screen.stop_animation()

    def closeEvent(self, a0) -> None:  # declare the close event to close the created window with the main application close
        try:
            self.loading_screen.stop_animation()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        self.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = AppWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```